# How to Logically DELETE a record in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, sqlitejdbc

I would like to mark a record as deleted instead of actually deleting a record.
My intention is to use an instead of trigger, but I am getting an SQLException that neither I nor Google know how to solve this.

**My code:**

```
    CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS <Trigger>
           INSTEAD OF DELETE ON <Table>
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
              UPDATE <Table>
              SET Status = 'D'
              WHERE ID = old.ID;                
            END
```

**My Error:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: cannot create INSTEAD OF trigger on table: main.<Table>
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
```

**Assist me, please?**

**EDIT:**
What I really wanted was to activate foreign key enforcement.

Refer here: [How do you enforce foreign key constraints in SQLite through Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774923/how-do-you-enforce-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite-through-java)

Comment: i think instead triggers only works with views

Comment: I not the best with SQLite, but should there be a declaration of "old"? like "INSTEAD OF DELETE ON <Table _old_>" or so?

Comment: sry, it is not OLD is correct, ignore my comment please

Comment: @Danis Under the heading "Instead of Trigger" [link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger)...Triggers may be created on views, as well as ordinary tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `INSTEAD OF` triggers on tables, and when `RAISE`-ing an error in `BEFORE`/`AFTER` triggers, any updates done in the trigger would also be rolled back.

You could rename your table, create a view for that table, and create lots of `INSTEAD OF` triggers to implement all the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations.

However, it would be much easier to change your program to just execute the `UPDATE` when it wants to mark some record.

Comment: Thanks CL and @ChrisProsser, I have decided to create a Before Delete trigger to "Prevent Delete" and then doing the marking with a normal UPDATE statement. Will consider writing a program to lock the table, drop the trigger, "really" delete irrelevant records, then reattaching the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggers are intended for use with views so that you can specify the underlying tables that an action should be carried out on when an insert, update our delete is issued on the view itself.

One thing you could try is to do a before delete trigger then raise an exception. The only thing is I'm not sure if this would also interfere with the update. Maybe worth a try though:

```
SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Prevent delete');
```