# How to correctly add Foreign Key constraints to SQLite DB using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm very new to SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to figure it out.

Please have in mind the following test setup:

```
class Nine(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nine'
    __table_args__ = (sqlalchemy.sql.schema.UniqueConstraint('nine_b', name='uq_nine_b'), )

    nine_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    nine_b = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(20), nullable=False)


class Seven(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'seven'
    __table_args__ = (sqlalchemy.sql.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint('seven_a', 'seven_b'),
                      sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Index('fk_seven_c_nine_a_idx', 'seven_c'),)

    seven_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), nullable=False)
    seven_b = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), nullable=False)
    seven_c = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('nine.nine_a'), nullable=False)
    seven_d = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), nullable=False)

    nine = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(Nine, backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('seven'), uselist=False)


class Three(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'three'
    __table_args__ = (sqlalchemy.sql.schema.UniqueConstraint('three_b', 'three_c', name='uq_three_b_c'),
                      sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Index('fk_three_c_seven_a_idx', 'three_c'), )

    three_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    three_b = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), nullable=False)
    three_c = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.INTEGER(), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('seven.seven_a'), nullable=False)

    seven = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(Seven, backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('three'), uselist=False)
```

That translates into the following DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE nine (
    nine_a INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    nine_b VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (nine_a), 
    CONSTRAINT uq_nine_b UNIQUE (nine_b)
);

CREATE TABLE seven (
    seven_a INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    seven_b INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    seven_c INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    seven_d INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (seven_a, seven_b), 
    FOREIGN KEY(seven_c) REFERENCES nine (nine_a)
);

CREATE INDEX fk_seven_c_nine_a_idx ON seven (seven_c);

CREATE TABLE three (
    three_a INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    three_b INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    three_c INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (three_a), 
    CONSTRAINT uq_three_b_c UNIQUE (three_b, three_c), 
    FOREIGN KEY(three_c) REFERENCES seven (seven_a)
);

CREATE INDEX fk_three_c_seven_a_idx ON three (three_c);
```

All tables are empty. Then, the following code statements:

```
session.add(Nine(nine_a=1, nine_b='something'))
session.add(Nine(nine_a=2, nine_b='something else'))
session.commit()

session.add(Seven(seven_a=7, seven_b=7, seven_c=7, seven_d=7))
session.commit()

session.add(Three(three_a=3, three_b=3, three_c=3))
sessionDB.commit()
```

Can somebody please explain why is the above code snippet executing without errors? Should't the FK constraints stop from inserting a new row into `seven` or `three`? I assume there is something wrong with how the FKs are described in the classes themselves, but I don't know where the problem is (and how to fix it).

[Edit 1]

Adding `__table_args__` for all classes (forgot to include them).

[Edit 2]

Adding DDLs for further reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite by default does not enforce ForeignKey constraints (see here http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys )

To enable, follow these docs here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

Here's a copy paste of the official documentation:

> SQLite supports FOREIGN KEY syntax when emitting CREATE statements for tables, however by default these constraints have no effect on the operation of the table.
>
> Constraint checking on SQLite has three prerequisites:
>
> - At least version 3.6.19 of SQLite must be in use
> - The SQLite library must be compiled without the SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER symbols enabled.
> - The `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` statement must be emitted on all connections before use.
>     SQLAlchemy allows for the PRAGMA statement to be emitted automatically for new connections through the usage of events:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: I'm issuing `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` before running the inserts (the command `PRAGMA foreign_keys` returns `1`. Unfortunately same results.

Comment: I've tested the FK constraint being ON at the DB level. But it appears that this needs to be turned ON per each connection ([http://stackoverflow.com/a/9835781/1237714](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9835781/1237714)). Things are starting to become **normal**. (Please include code snippet (e.g., using events) in answer.)