# How do I enable foreign key constraints for SQLite with Dropwizard and JDBI?

Tags: java, sqlite, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm using Dropwizard and its [JDBI module](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/jdbi.html) in order to connect to an SQLite database. I've setup the database so that it has FKs in place, but I still need to tell SQLite to enable its constraints.

I know you can configure it [using a properties instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13377015/1891491), but I don't see how to make use of that together with the JDBI setup in Dropwizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following property to your .yml settings file: `foreign_keys: true`.

It should look something like this:

```
database:
  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: org.sqlite.JDBC

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:sqlite:databasefile.db

  # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
  properties:
    foreign_keys: true
```

After that you should have FK constraint in your SQLite database. You can check out the `SQLiteConfig` class for more properties.