# How can I delete row from parent table has a referenced column to child table?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlitejdbc

I'm using JDBC in javaFx project with SQlite database. I have two tables `"PROJECT"` and `"SMAllPROJECT"` such as PROJECT has this structure `PROJECT(name,date,state)` and `SMAllPROJECT` has this structure `SMAllPROJECT(name,date,state,*project_name*)`. `Project_name` is referenced from `name` column of `PROJECT table`.

I'm trying to delete row from `PROJECT` and the rows referenced in `SMAllPoject` should be deleted. In sqlite studio I configure `onCascade` method when I apply delete a row from parent table and every thing is well when I test it in SQlite studio, but in my code it deleted rows just from parent table.

This is my code :

**Controller method**

```
public void ExecuteDeleteProject() {

        if (!SearchIdProjectSupp.getText().isEmpty()) {

            Project project = new ProjectDao().FindString(SearchIdProjectSupp.getText());
            new ProjectDao().Delete(project);
            String title = "Suppression";
            String message = "Vous avez supprimé le projet " + SearchIdProjectSupp.getText() + ".";
            NotificationType notification = NotificationType.SUCCESS;
            TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
            tray.setTitle(title);
            tray.setMessage(message);
            tray.setNotificationType(notification);
            tray.setAnimationType(AnimationType.SLIDE);
            tray.setImage(new Image("Images/check.png"));
            tray.setRectangleFill(Paint.valueOf("#a8a9fe"));
            tray.showAndDismiss(Duration.seconds(4));
            SearchIdProjectSupp.setText("");
            SuppPaneProject.setVisible(false);
            DeleteProjetButton.setDisable(true);
            CountP.setVisible(true);
            CountP();
            CountR();
            CountPP();

        }

    }
```

**DAO pattern method**

```
public boolean Delete(Project Object) {

        try {

            String queryDeletePerson = "DElETE FROM PROJECT WHERE name=" + "'" + Object.getName() + "'";//Query Insertion in Person_Table

            PreparedStatement preparedStatementPerson = Dbaconnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(queryDeletePerson);//Prepared statement i use this for high performance 

            preparedStatementPerson.execute();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(EMPDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And this is my DDL

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
    NAME VARCHAR2 (100) PRIMARY KEY,
    STATE  VARCHAR2 (100),
    DATEDBT DATE,
 );

CREATE TABLE SMALLPROJECT (
    NAMEPROJECT       VARCHAR2 (100) REFERENCES PROJECT (NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                                          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    NAME VARCHAR2 (20)  PRIMARY KEY,
    DATEDBT     DATE,
    STATE VARCHAR2 (20)  PRIMARY KEY

    );
```

Comment: Can you share the tables' definitions please (not just the column list, but the actual DDLs used to create them)?

Comment: @Mureinik, i shared actual DDLs used to create them.

Comment: When you establish your JDBC connection to the SQLite database do you explicitly enable foreign keys, either by executing `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` or by using an `SQLiteConfig` object?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine these DDLs produce multiple errors. Are you sure these are your DDLs?

Comment: @GordThompson ,no i did not do this step.

Comment: @GordThompson i'm using SQLite JDBC driver and  `stmnt.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")` is not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Comment: I just tested with "sqlite-jdbc-3.18.0.jar" from the [Maven Central repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.xerial%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sqlite-jdbc%22) and it works fine.

Comment: @GordThompson I used SQLiteConfig object and it works perfect,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [SQLite Foreign Key Support](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) and the answer of [How do you enforce foreign key constraints in SQLite through Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774923/how-do-you-enforce-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite-through-java)

,it should configure database connection before execute any query.I had this problem because i did not enforce foreign key constraints.

```
public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";  
public static final String DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";  

public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {  
    Class.forName(DRIVER);  
    Connection connection = null;  
    try {  
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig(); //I add this configuration 
        config.enforceForeignKeys(true);  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,config.toProperties());  
    } catch (SQLException ex) {}  
    return connection;  
}
```